# Changes in new linux kernel 4.4.2 distributed with SLES 12 SP2 causing driver build failure

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, suse, sles

I am building my SLES 12 driver (block device driver) with 3.x kernel on SLES 12 SP2 which has kernel version 4.4.2 . Now I am facing problem with few things:

1. > struct bvec_merge_data

   is not available in kernel 4.3.0 onwards in include/linux/blkdev.h

   struct bvec_merge_data { 
   struct block_device *bi_bdev;
   sector_t bi_sector;
   unsigned bi_size;
   unsigned long bi_rw; 
   };
2. from 4.2.8 onward this funtion pointer is not present. What might be the alternative method is provided in 4.3 or higher versions.

> typedef int (merge_bvec_fn) (struct request_queue *, struct
>   bvec_merge_data *,
>                  struct bio_vec *);

3. In the request_queue structure the below structure elements are removed form 4.2.8 where these elemments are handled
   struct request_queue {

> unprep_rq_fn      *unprep_rq_fn;
>
> merge_bvec_fn     *merge_bvec_fn;

Any idea where can I look for these changes and and any alternative for those?

Answer (score 1):

Best place for such answers is git log of kernel source. Supplying -S switch will search within the diff content. Supplying -G will do same but with regular expressions.

In this case running `git log -S "bvec_merge_data"` shows information on changes related to this struct and, by association, `merge_bvec_fn` method. Here's snapshot of the top message which talks about *complete* removal of struct `bvec_merge_data`:

> commit 8ae126660fddbeebb9251a174e6fa45b6ad8f932 Author: Kent
>   Overstreet  Date:   Mon Apr 27 23:48:34
>   2015 -0700
>
> ```
> block: kill merge_bvec_fn() completely
>
> As generic_make_request() is now able to handle arbitrarily sized bios,
> it's no longer necessary for each individual block driver to define its
> own ->merge_bvec_fn() callback. Remove every invocation completely.
> ```

Other commit message preceding this one show the build up to it, which can be a good step-by-step explanation to your question.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks @bytefire. We are going to try it and would update if there is any further query or useful info found.

Comment: @Durgesh in fact, subsequent commit messages give more detail. E.g. commit 0e28997ec476b says bio splitting (which seems related to bvec_merge_data) is not required because now arbitrarily large bios can be handled. You can also see how others have handled removal of merge_bvec_fn and the struct by `git show <commit-hash>`